# Selenium Web automation - Send values to Disabled text box

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, selenium

We are testing a *ASPNET MVC Application* by using ***Selenium***.

In the Webpage they are using a Jquery Date control Textbox [datepicker/#icon-trigger](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) 
and that text box was in **Disable mode**

I am trying to send the values from selenium to webpage by using following code.

```
    Driver.findElement(By.id("txtDOB")).sendKeys("10/10/1986");
```

But it was not working. it doesn't show any error.

and Now My question is ***`how to send values to Disabled text box?`***

Can any one help me on this...?

Comment: The answer is: Don't.   It's extremely bad test logic to perform actions that a user can't do (another example would be to set a hidden input value.)

Answer (score 2):

Well you have two approaches here

1. Do it like a user would do and use the query date picker [see here (untested)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295739/selenium-web-driver-selection-of-date-from-jquery-datepicker-ui)
2. Enable the text box and then set the field something like this:

   ```
   WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("xxx"));
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].enabled = true", textbox);
   ```

Comment: i have already try this code. I enable the textbox and then try sendkeys.. but no luck.. is there any other way..?

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend that you script this so that it uses the date picker, in the exact same way a user would have to pick a date, as the user is not allowed to type in their own date.

If really must work around this, then you could try forcing a value into the textbox using javascript:

```js
IWebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("txtDOB")); 
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='10/10/1986'", textbox);
```