# unable to input values with send_keys in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm unable to give values to a text field as below (it is leaving the field blank):

```
 browser.find_element_by_name("userId").clear()   
 browser.find_element_by_name("userId").send_keys('myname')
```

This is the html part of the text field im trying to give value:

```
<td align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="userCB" type="checkbox" onclick="disable_enable_user(checked)"/> User ID<br /></td>
<td align="left">
<input name="userId" type="text" size="15" value="" disabled="disabled">
```

Is it because the field is disabled, if so , how can I enable it?

Comment: Question likes your:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689963/selenium-web-automation-send-values-to-disabled-text-box

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute value of an element by using the JavascriptExecutor (the example is in JAVA but you can get the idea):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('element id').setAttribute('attrName', 'value')");
```

In general, it's not a good practice to try to set a value to a disabled field (even by manipulation) if the goal is test automation.
You should automate a form AS IS and look for workarounds only if:

1. the "user flow" can't be automated otherwise
2. this specific test is not important

hope this helps

Comment: Hi , I am able to pass the value like browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('endDate_Year_ID').value = '2013'") but the values are not getting reflected finally. The default values are only picked